# Wrapper around xdef to check for conflicts

Tags: macros, expansion

How can I write transparent wrapper around `xdef` that, depending on package options, report error, override or obey previous definition without sacrificing all flexibility? I have no idea how to pass all this `#` in.

EDIT: Example what I can do and what I want to do:

```
%% This is not valid. xdef have different syntax.
%% \ifpackage@force\xdef\package@define\xdef\fi
\ifpackage@obey\xdef\package@define\providecommand\fi
\ifpackage@err\xdef\package@define\newcommand\fi
```

So I can have generic interface for `providecommand` and `newcommand`. I want add checking in `xdef`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A package?

Comment: Yes. Package with options, controlling what to do with conflicts.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a minimal working example to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Do you mean similar to `\newcommand` in the sense of checking for an existing definition, _etc._?

Comment: @JosephWright Exactly! Generic interface for defining TeX-style macros, with three implementations --- signal error on conflict, preserve previous defiinition and override it.

Comment: you could define a command like `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` but which used `\xdef` rather than `\def` internally, but it would be a bad idea to redefine `\xdef` to add checking capability, it would almost certainly break latex.

Comment: I would add that exposing `\edef` `\xdef` to users is very likely to break code and perhaps `\protected@edef` and `\protected@xdef` should be used internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

something like this

```
\begin{filecontents}{cxdef.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{cxdef}[2013/05/30]

\DeclareOption{over}{\let\myxdef\xdef}
\DeclareOption{error}{\let\myxdef\errorxdef}
\DeclareOption{preserve}{\let\myxdef\preservexdef}


\def\errorxdef#1{%
\ifx#1\@undefined
  \expandafter\xdef
\else
  \PackageError{cxdef}{\string#1 already defined}{think of a new name}%
  \expandafter\skip@xdef
\fi
#1}


\def\preservexdef#1{%
\ifx#1\@undefined
  \expandafter\xdef
\else
  \expandafter\skip@xdef
\fi
#1}

\def\skip@xdef#1#{\@gobble}

\ExecuteOptions{over}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[error]{cxdef}

\myxdef\mbox#1#2\zz{this is bad}

\myxdef\zzzz#1#2\zz{this is good}

\typeout{\meaning\zzzz}


\stop
```

which produces

```
! Package cxdef Error: \mbox already defined.

See the cxdef package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.39 \myxdef\mbox
                 #1#2\zz{this is bad}
? 
macro:#1#2\zz ->this is good
 )
```

`\xdef`, `\errorxdef` and `\preservexdef` are available or you can use `\myxdef` which is `\let` to one of those three depending on a package option.

As egreg noted in a comment on the question, it would be better to use `\protected@xdef` rather than `\xdef` wherever the latter appears in the package code, but I'll leave as `\xdef` for now as that was the original question.

Answer (score 5):

This answer tries to answer the question, if `\xdef` can be replaced by a macro to catch the command to be defined.

The syntax of `\xdef` is quite complicate, the relevant aspects:

1. `\xdef` is unexpandable.
2. The definition can be prefixed by `\long`, `\outer`, and e-TeX adds `\protected`.
3. `\afterassignment` might insert a token right after the definition.

Vanilla TeX already fails issue 1. At least e-TeX provides an approximation, if
the new macro is defined using `\protected`.

Issue 2 is tried by the following example for various formats with e-TeX (`etex`, `pdflatex`):

```
\catcode`\@=11 % same as \makeatletter
\def\msg#{\immediate\write16}% short for printing something on the console

\let\xdef@original\xdef

\def\xdef@test@{}
\long\def\xdef@test@L{}
\protected\def\xdef@test@P{}
\protected\long\def\xdef@test@PL{}

\outer\def\xdef@test@O{}
\long\outer\def\xdef@test@LO{}
\protected\outer\def\xdef@test@PO{}
\protected\long\outer\def\xdef@test@PLO{}

\protected\def\xdef{%
  \def\xdef@test{}%
  \edef\xdef@prefix{%
    \ifx     \xdef@test\xdef@test@
    \else\ifx\xdef@test\xdef@test@L
      \noexpand\long
    \else\ifx\xdef@test\xdef@test@P
      \noexpand\protected
    \else\ifx\xdef@test\xdef@test@PL
      \noexpand\protected
      \noexpand\long
    \else
      \xdef@test@outer
    \fi\fi\fi\fi
  }%
  \xdef@check
}

\def\xdef@test@outer{%
  \expandafter\ifx     \csname xdef@test\expandafter\endcsname
                       \csname xdef@test@O\endcsname
    \noexpand\outer
  \else\expandafter\ifx\csname xdef@test\expandafter\endcsname
                       \csname xdef@test@LO\endcsname
    \noexpand\long
    \noexpand\outer
  \else\expandafter\ifx\csname xdef@test\expandafter\endcsname
                       \csname xdef@test@PO\endcsname
    \noexpand\protected
    \noexpand\outer
  \else\expandafter\ifx\csname xdef@test\expandafter\endcsname
                       \csname xdef@test@PLO\endcsname
    \noexpand\protected
    \noexpand\long
    \noexpand\outer
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}

\edef\xdef@test@undefined{\meaning\xdef@undefined}
\edef\xdef@test@relax{\meaning\relax}
\def\xdef@check#1{%
  \edef\xdef@test{\meaning#1}%
  \ifx\xdef@test\xdef@test@undefined
    \chardef\xdef@ok=1 %
  \else\ifx\xdef@test\xdef@test@relax
    \chardef\xdef@ok=1 %
  \else
    \chardef\xdef@ok=0 %
  \fi\fi
  \ifcase\xdef@ok
    \errmessage{\string#1 is already defined}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\xdef@dummy   
  \or
    \expandafter\xdef@prefix
    \expandafter\xdef@original\expandafter#1%
  \fi
}

% testing
\xdef\aaa{}
\long\xdef\bbb{}
\protected\xdef\ccc{}
\protected\long\xdef\ddd{}
\outer\xdef\eee{}
\long\outer\xdef\fff{}
\protected\outer\xdef\ggg{}
\protected\long\outer\xdef\hhh{}
\xdef\iii{}

% end of job (LaTeX or plain TeX)
\csname @@end\endcsname\end
```

The prefixes can only be caught another definition, therefore the new `\xdef` starts with the definition of `\xdef@test`. Then the new definition is tested against a series of other macros to find the prefixes that was active.
Prefix `\outer` complicates the testing because of its nature. There are restrictions, where `\outer` macros can be used.
The found prefixes are stored in `\xdef@prefix`.

Then the new command token is tested, if it is undefined or has the meaning of `\relax` (LaTeX's interpretation of "undefined" in `\@ifundefined`).
This is checked via `\meaning`. An error is thrown, if the new command is already defined and a dummy command `\xdef@dummy` is defined instead.

However this redefined `\xdef` is **NOT** a valid replacement for the original `\xdef`. It fails issue 3, the `\afterassignment` feature:

- Expandable stuff between the prefixes and the final definition does not hurt.
  Thus we could test for the command to be defined. But throwing an error message
  (or printing a warning) is not expandable and TeX complains:

  ```
  ! You can't use a prefix with `\errmessage'.
  ```

  Therefore we need at least one test definition to catch the prefixes.
- If `\afterassignment` is in use, then the token is inserted right after
  the first test definition, way to early:

  - The inserted token might want to use the new definition, that is not yet
    defined.
  - The definition business is not finished. The token might want to clean up some stuff and mess up things.

Thus I am pretty sure, that there is no way with TeX or e-TeX that can simulate *all* aspects of `\xdef` by a macro that catches the command to be defined to print warnings or to throw errors, if the command is already defined.